# How to troubleshoot API requests sent by Ansible module?

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-awx, nutanix

**Here's the context:**
The following playbook (simplified to one task for this Stack Overflow topic and for ease of use) got different results depends on where I launch it. It uses the nutanix.ncp galaxy collection (tested with version 1.9.0, 1.8.0, 1.7.0...)

The `ntnx_subnets_info` method is called to retrieve all the list of existing subnet on a prism central instance, and is filtered through the name parameter to retrieve only details of a specific VLAN.

```
---
- name: test-get-subnet-info
  hosts: localhost

  vars:
    nutanix_host: "{{ XXXXXXX }}"
    nutanix_username: "{{ XXXXXXX }}"
    nutanix_password: "XXXXXXX "

  collections:
    - nutanix.ncp
  module_defaults:
    group/nutanix.ncp.ntnx:
      nutanix_host: "{{ XXXXXXX }}"
      nutanix_username: "{{ XXXXXXX }}"
      nutanix_password: "XXXXXXX "

  tasks:
  - name: Retrieve subnet info
    ntnx_subnets_info:
      filter:
        name: "my-VLAN"
```

On a Debian 11 server, this task run smoothly as you can see below:

[image]

Whereas on my custom AWX EE (tested both with docker then on K8s) I got the following error which isn't too explicit:

> Failed to convert API response to json

[image]

**Troubleshoot steps:**

- try to downgrade nutanix.ncp collection from 1.9.0 to 1.8.0 and 1.7.0 => still the same results (works on debian, not from docker)
- compare ansible version => both environment run on ansible core 2.15.4
- compare python version => docker image environment is on 3.9.17 and debian server on 3.9.2
- launch manual curl requests from both environment => **everything works on both environment**
- launch the playbook with -vvvvvv option and compare differences on the log => nutanix.ncp is not so chatty, I don't get any other errors as you can see on the screenshot beyond.

**Questions**

- Is there a way to "analyze" Ansible API requests, like a wireshark/fiddler for Ansible ?
- how can I go further to troubleshoot and fix this issue? As it works on one side but not on the others I may compare some stuff and hopefully find a difference?

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Just post the text itself, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: You don't need an Ansible-specific tool to analyze the requests. If they're made over http, regular tcpdump/wireshark will be sufficient. If they're made over https, set up a logging web server or use a service like [postbin](https://www.toptal.com/developers/postbin/) to capture and analyze the request.

Comment: @larsks sorry for the pictures. My query was like , does ansible got an embedded tool (which may use the troubleshoot) anyway , I'll check if it's possible to tcpdump/wireshark from a docker container or from K8s (to me it's a bit different to do it here from a traditional vm) I wasn't aware of postbin, i'll have a check thanks !

Comment: After tshark/tcpdumping + double check with openssl query, I found out i got a verify return code 20 - unable to get local issuer certificate. We agree it means that my docker image should contains only my root ca or the whole cert chain ? (root ca + intermediate ca + custom cert). Should it be .pem or .cer base 64 encoded ?

Comment: Glad you made forward progress! You may want to open a new question for that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tests and investigations, just found entity.py in nutanix.ncp collection files. It was the file that is responsible of msg "Failed to convert API response to json"

- One function sends the error message when URL response received code is >300.
  I went into a wireshark capture and figured out there was an error in the network flows :
  [image]
- Then, it bring me to check connection from my docker image / K8s pod to my Prism Central.

  The command `openssl s_client -connect fqdn_prism_central:9440` shows the error message

> “ Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)"

- Finally, I just update certificate chain on my docker image (through my Dockerfile) and everything is now fine in AWX.

  In my case, as AWX EE image is based on official awx-ee (https://quay.io/repository/ansible/awx-ee?tab=tags&tag=latest), I add the following steps to my dockerfile (note : path and command may differs if you're using something else than CentOS image) :

```
COPY ./certificate_chain.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/certificate_chain.pem
RUN chmod 644 /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/certificate_chain.pem && update-ca-trust extract
```

Pretty tough, but it works great ! :)